# How to get the output of Process.exec in crystal-lang?

Tags: shell, process, exec, crystal-lang

I need to get the output of Process.exec (not Process.run) as a string in crystal. Can this be done?

I've tried

```
Process.exec base, args
```

But it only puts it to the console. I'd like to put it in a variable.

Comment: `Process.exec` will replace the current process (your running program) with the one you indicate. So no, it's not what you want. Why not use `Process.run`?

Comment: @bew Well, I'm using `Process.exec` inside `Process.fork`. I'm looking to capture the output of `Process.fork`.

Comment: You'll need a few pipes then (3 if you want std{in, out, err}), you can create one with `IO.pipe`. If you need to do custom things before exec'ing your process, I'd suggest you to read how `Process.run` is implemented to see an example of use of pipes to control a process and get its output!

Comment: Here https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/0a3070b1d84e8936999e9be9ca180c47c2b6f7b1/src/process.cr#L239

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already clarified in comments, you can't capture output of a process executed using `Process.exec`, but there are ways to execute a process and capture it's output.

The most straightforward one - backticks:

```
output = `echo "Hello world"`
```

In more complex scenarios (e.g. you need to capture standard output and standard error output separately, need to get also it's status, or to have greater control over it's execution) you can use something like this:

```
stdout = IO::Memory.new
process = Process.new("echo", ["Hello world"], output: stdout)
status = process.wait
output = stdout.to_s
```

or

```
stdout = IO::Memory.new
status = Process.run("echo", ["Hello world"], output: stdout)
output = stdout.to_s
```